# How to get the object key it has the value

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, object

I have a filter component which user can choose any data to filter so I store this data in state.when I want to create a params for query some of the field not choosen by user I only wanna get the one which has value here is the code ;

```
function createParams(params = {}) {
    let result = "?";
    for (let key in params) {
        result += `${key}=${params[key]}&`;
    }
    return result;
}

export async function callApi(params) {
    const parameters = createParams(params);
    try {
        const response = await fetch(URL+ parameters);
        const res = await response.json();
        return res;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
        throw error;
    }
}

export const requestProperties = (params) => callApi(params);

const requestedParams = {type:"Fiat", model:"500", color:""};
```

I only want to get the type and model because it has been choosen by user to filter. I dont wanna include the colour

Thank you..:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take `entries` and then filter out the records.

```js
var requestedParams = {type:"Fiat", model:"500", color:""};
var result = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(requestedParams).filter(([k,v])=>v));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can destructure the object if you only want to exclude one key-value pair

```js
const requestedParams = {type:"Fiat", model:"500", color:""};
const exclude = 'color';

const {[exclude]: remove, ...rest} = requestedParams;

console.log(rest);
```

If you have multiple key-value pairs that you want to exclude, you can use reduce function

```js
const requestedParams = { type: "Fiat", model: "500", color: "" };

const res = Object.entries(requestedParams).reduce((acc, curr) => {
  return curr[1] ? (acc[curr[0]] = curr[1], acc) : acc;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```